# Please delete 17394

Tags: support, specific-question

Can somebody please delete my obscure [question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/17394/what-are-the-requirements-for-ccmail-interactive-mode) about technology nobody uses, and which seems unlikely to lead to anything useful. The existing answer does not even attempt to address the question, it is just a general report on an episode in the poster's life that happens to involve some of the same products.

Comment: Does it not let you do it yourself? Anyway, I think the question is valuable, even if that answer isn't; are you sure it can't just be left undeleted but unanswered?

Comment: I thought that check was only for positive-score answers. You can delete the question now.

Answer (score 3):

Thinking that a question is not valuable is not a valid reason for deletion.

I see no reason for the question to be deleted.

Thank you for your concern regarding the quality of the site as a whole, that is appreciated.  However, the general rule is to delete questions only if they are off-topic (or spam of course).

If you wish to delete this particular question, then so be it.

Comment: Automatic deletion of unanswered questions below a certain score (regardless of whether they were closed or flagged) seems to put a lie to that ‘general rule’.

Comment: Yes, other reasons for deletion do exist.  That's why I said 'general', to not overcomplicate the answer.

Comment: The point is, the question score is supposed to be a proxy for quality. So the value of the question *is* a consideration as to whether it should stay or not; it’s just that it’s (usually) supposed to be determined by the voters, not the asker. (Though I assume this is meant as protection against perverse incentives, not an inherent disqualification.)